# Scroll progress indicator not working with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js

I am quite new with Javascript and I am creating a new portfolio website for myself. Currently I am facing an issue with the progress indicator on scroll. It isn’t working. It was working until I added fullpage.js. I have attached my code below and would love to know how to fix this.

Thank you!!

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Aaron</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-4rPgyv5iG0PZw8E+oRdfN/Gq+yilzt9rQ8Yci2jJ15rAyBmF0HBE4wFjBkoB72cxBeg63uobaj1UcNt/scV93w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <!-- <header>
      <h4 class="logo">LIGHT</h4>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> -->

  <div id="fullpage">




                    <div class="section one">
                      Section ONE
                    </div>

                    <div class="section two">
                      Section TWO
                    </div>

                    <div class="section three">
                      Section THREE
                    </div>

                    <div class="section four">
                      Section FOUR
                    </div>




  </div>

  <div class="progress-section">
    <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-num"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- Main Container Ends -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.1.2/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-gSf3NCgs6wWEdztl1e6vUqtRP884ONnCNzCpomdoQ0xXsk06lrxJsR7jX5yM/qAGkPGsps+4bLV5IEjhOZX+gg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>



</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#111111;
  color: white;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.progress-section {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  wil-change: transform;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress-bar-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
}

/* .section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
} */

.one {
  background: gray;
}

.two {
  background: dark gray;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}

.four {
  background: purple;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    let progressSection = document.querySelector('.progress-section');
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
let progressNum = document.querySelector('.progress-num');

let x,y;


function updateProgressBar(){

  progressBar.style.height = `${getScrollPercentage()}%`;
  progressNum.innerText = `${Math.ceil(getScrollPercentage())}%`
  requestAnimationFrame(updateProgressBar)
}

function getScrollPercentage(){
  return ((window.scrollY) / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)*100)
};

updateProgressBar()

;


new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'My License Key :)',
  autoScrolling: true,

})
```

Comment: Does it give you any error in the console?

Comment: Hi. It doesn't show any errors in the console no :(

Comment: I tried your code in my local. It says that it requires a liceseKey.

https://prnt.sc/1gx6yaf << errors

Comment: Hi. I have one and having a licence key doesn’t change the issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scroll indicator relies on the scroll position of the page.
fullPage.js by default uses CSS3 hardware-accelerated animations and therefore won't use "scrollable" content but rather simulate the scroll with css3 transitions.

To fix this use the fullPage.js option `scrollBar: true` as in this example.
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html

Code here:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrollBar.html

Comment: You are a legend sir. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Feel free to accept the  answer by clicking on the tick on my answer. This way others can identify this as the fix to your issue :)

Comment: Hi Alvaro once again thank you. One last thing. I am trying to implement a way where the progress indicator changes colour depending on the background color. (E.g black progress indicator on white background and white on black background)

Comment: You can use fullpage.js callbacks to do so with JS or you can use the [CSS state classes that fullpage.js provides](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) so you can do things like `.fp-viewing-page2-0 #nav{ color: red}`;

Comment: Again thank you for your help. I am still playing around with Javascript so I have no clue where to start. As a last request, would you be able to give me an example please?

Comment: It is for the  <div class="progress-section"> of my code by the way.

Comment: Hi Alvaro I have tried it but unfortunately it does not work. https://codepen.io/Azzaa95/pen/mdmxaxg